# What are the limitations of OneDrive for Business APIs

Tags: onedrive

As per the documention of the OneDrive API https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm, under the Throttling option, "OneDrive has limits in place to make sure that individuals and apps do not adversely affect the experience of other users. When an activity exceeds OneDrive's limits, API requests will be rejected for a period of time. OneDrive may also return a Retry-After header with the number of seconds your app should wait before sending more requests."

So i would like to know what are the limitations that causes the OneDriveApi to reject request

Answer (score 0):

Based on how use the API many requests to it or if you are trying to do something that the user is not info need abt